# ¿Cómo extraigo datos de una página web con una programa de consola Pascal?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

Bueno básicamente lo que estoy tratando de hacer es poder acedera una página web ejemplo
https://telegra.ph/Ejemplo-para-Stack-Overflow-05-15
Y sacar de allí información para guardarla en unas variables para luego trabajar con ellas.
En la página está el precio de los siguientes productos: carne, pescado, leche huevo y los precio de los camiones de agua por su capacidad
Yo intente ser creativo y pensé que si obtengo el código fuente de la página podría extraer la información de allí y así poder trabajarla con el programa pero no encuentro como hacerlo como tal.

yo estuve buscando por internet y me conseguí con esta pagina
http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Internet_Tools

y hice el siguiente código tratando de mostrar la página por consola

```
Program prueba;
uses simpleinternet;
var str:string;
begin
  str := retrieve('http://www.google.de');
end.
```

No sé si yo soy bruto porque no me compila pero me dice que no se pudieron encontrar la siguiente librería simpleinternet
Entonces no sé si yo estoy haciendo algo mal o que en verdad  eso no me funciona.
Lo otro que se me ocurrió hacer es utilizar Curl para descargar el código fuente de la página pero no sé cómo llamarlo desde el programa que estoy haciendo
Yo sé que utilizando Curl puedo descargar el código fuente de una página web de la siguiente forma
Curl.exe Link_a_descarga > archivo_acumulador.txt
eso me guardaria el html de la pagina en un archivo de texto llamado: "archivo_acumulador.txt"
Pero nose como hacer que se ejecute en un programa
Espero que me puedna ayudar

Comment: Internet Tools es una biblioteca que debes descargar (y su dependencia, que es Synapse). El sitio oficial de la biblioteca es: [Internet tools](http://benibela.de/sources_en.html#internettools). En esa descarga está la unidad `simpleinternet` que buscas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si puedes utilizar componentes, con un `TIdHttp` es suficiente para obtener el contenido de la página.
Un programa como este:

```
program ProjectConsole;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}
uses
  System.SysUtils, IdHTTP;

begin
  try
    with TIdHTTP.Create(nil) do
    try
      // Acceder a la web
      WriteLn(Get('https://telegra.ph/Ejemplo-para-Stack-Overflow-05-15'));
      ReadLn;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Con algo como esto consigues el contenido del HTML.

[image: Salida del programa de consola]

A partir de ahí puedes hacer un "parse" del contenido que te interese, para extraerlo.